# Extending HTML5 tags collection

Tags: xml, html

As you know HTML5 introduced  some new html tag, like footer,header, ...

What prevent us from using a lot of other new tag and apply shiv to these new tags? (from functional, behavior, style, structure, ... viewpoints)

I want use following code (more semantic, concise and readable, a step forward Web 3.0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    book {
        display: block;
        color: red;
    }

    book title {
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<book>
    <title>
        My Title
    </title>
</book>
```

instead of using following traditional (!) code:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        div.book {
            color: red;
        }

        div.book div.title {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="book">
        <span class="title">My title</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own tags works well up to a point, and it sounds tempting. However, you are not adding any meaning (semantics) that way; an invented tag has no defined meaning, and pretending that the tag *name* is descriptive of meaning is an illusion.

[Custom tags have several problems](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/pragmatic-html.html8#custom). But your simple example also demonstrates extended usage of tags that are defined in HTML specifications. Who knows what will happen if a document contains several `title` elements, or a `title` element outside its  “legal” scope, the `head` element? Who knows what search engines will think about it?

The point is that `title` is defined in HTML and browsers treat it in their ways, which cannot be controlled by you. If the browser decides to take a misplaced `title` element as if it were standard-conformingly in the `head` and therefore uses it in certain ways (e.g., in top bar or tab control), what can you do about it? If it even overrides a standard-conforming `title` element, what do you do?

If you just use custom tags, you might decide to ignore the IE problem (which cannot be completely solved using JavaScript, because JavaScript might be disabled). But you would still be using something that may crash tomorrow when some browser vendor starts supporting an extended tag and it happens to have the same name as your tag (but different meaning). And `<book>` is a good candidate for that. It might even make its way to HTML specs some day; HTML5 drafts already have `<article>`.

Your style sheet might override any default *presentation* describable in CSS today, but browsers might use extended CSS features or might use presentational features not describable in CSS. And new tags might have default *functionality* that surprises you and can hardly be anticipated now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I do not use pre-defined tags and choose special word like 'xyz-book' instead of 'book', is there any other issues?

Comment: @Reza, if you use tag names that will probably not be taken into use in future browsers and specifications, then you are relatively safe. But then you lose much of the benefits, which are in code readability; `<xyz-book>...</xyz-book>` does not look much better than `<div class=book>...</div>`.

Comment: @ Jukka K. Korpela  W3C can propose a standard prefix (for example 'd-')for custom tags, like 'data-' prefix for custom attributes, after that world of web whould be more beautiful!

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a use case for RDFa. Actually, there is a very similar example in the [RDFa specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/). Here is what you can do (I know, it's more verbose than what you propose but who said that more semantics means more conciseness?)

```
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  prefix="bibo: http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/
          dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the web page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      div[typeof="bibo:Book"] {
        color: red;
      }
      span[property="dc:title"] {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div typeof="bibo:Book">
      <span property="dc:title">My title</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, you are saying that there is an entity of type `bibo:Book` (you need to define a namespace which refer to a vocabulary, here the [Bibliography ontology](http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/)) and this entity has a `dc:title` (again, the property is defined in the [Dublin Core](http://purl.org/dc/terms/) vocabulary).
You can see that I'm using CSS2 selectors to format the book as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is why mentioned code is not widely used while it is more semantic, concise and readable.

Comment: With RDFa, you can gently enrich HTML without disturbing it. For example, if you have a `<h1>` element which is also the title of a book, you can simply add a `property`attribute to it. Moreover, with RDFa, you can express arbitrary graph structures, while you are limited to tree structures with XML markups. Additionally, RDFa is a standard so there is no way it can be missinterpreted by a conformant browser. Finally, RDFa encodes RDF, so it can also be indexed by Semantic Web search engines, queried with SPARQL, integrated in a triple store, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`<title>` is already an element in HTML. Do you know what happens if you do this in all HTML consumers? In IE8 and earlier for example?

Even if you restrict yourself to elements that don't currently exist in HTML, how can you prevent an element of the same name being invented in the future, with behaviour in browsers that breaks your page?

Comment: 1: We can use HTML5shiv method for older IEs. 2:This is not an important issue, because our pages already overrided (or can be edited to override) future new HTML tags. (Like CSS-Reset method)

Comment: @Reza - 1. No you can't, it won't fix this problem. 2. No you can't, not always. Try displaying the contents of the `<audio>` tag for instance using CSS. I suggest you try out these things rather than assuming.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done in raw XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="main.css" type="text/css"?>
<Root>
  <book>
    <title>
      My Title
    </title>
  </book>
</Root>
```

and main.css:

```
book {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}

book title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Concise enough?

Comment: Don't see how this is relevant

Comment: This is a valid idea, IMO, but you would need an XSLT to get back to a browsable web page.

Comment: @WilliamGreenly See Alohci's answer. Trying to invent new elements and reusing existing elements in HTML is a terrible idea! Besides, the OP's example doesn't even display anything in IE7 and IE8. So I was trying to provide some alternate way of getting what the OP needs, rather than helping along the wrong path.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann You can use XSLT, yes, but even a simple `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attribute on the `Root` start tag would make my example browsable! (Oh well, not in IE.)

Comment: @Mr Lister I also think that your code is prefect. But I want know why XML-based pages are not widely used for website design.

Can you include js files in the XML file? What about jquery?
Can we use XML and design all thing that HTML can generate ? (For example <form> element).

If we can, Is XML-based web pages compatible with major web browsers?

Can you please mention a few web site that use XML (Web 3.0 web pages)

Comment: @Reza If you need that functionality, you should go with XSLT. You'll have a lot of work making that behave as you want though. And if readability is important to you, an XSL stylesheet file is not a pleasant sight to look at. In that case, you might be better off with the simple `class` system you referred to as "traditional (!) code". And in the end, how important is the readability of the page source to your users?